# Form POST wont transfer variables to PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms, post, http-post

I have this problem that I haven't been able to fix for days now and I am going crazy...

I have a HTML form and I am trying to pass those variables from the form over to my PHP script but for some reason they are not passing over.

HTML Form:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <a name="contactus"></a>
                <div class="contact-form bottom">
                    <h2>Send a message</h2>
                    <form  name="contact form" method="POST" action="sendemail_1.php" id="main-contact-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text"  name="name" id="names" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="email"  name="email" id="emails" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text"  name="number" id="numbers" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <textarea name="message" id="messages" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Full PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                            
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     
$mail->Username = '*****@gmail.com';          
$mail->Password = '****';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  
$mail->Port = 587;                         
$mail->setFrom('*****@gmail.com', 'Test');
$mail->addReplyTo('****@gmail.com', 'Test');
$mail->addAddress("****@hotmail.com"); 

$mail->isHTML(false);  // Set email format to HTML

$bodyContent = "test";
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message');

$mail->Subject = 'Test';
$mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';    
}
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

The JS used

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**I have also tried it with the $_POST('name') but it also does not work.**

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: so any error you are facing ? or it shows only blank ?

Comment: Blanks, no errors. Thanks!

Comment: try to print post and request variables. print_r($_POST); print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: are these two files in the same directory?

Comment: Yes in the same directory. it sends the email, it just doesnt include any of the variables they are all blank

Comment: I don't believe you are checking for errors. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php see what comes of it. Set it to catch and display and view any (error) logs you may have access to, then post it in your question as an edit, if there are any.

Comment: Also, how are you using this, on your own pc? If so, how? As `http://localhost` or `file:///`?

Comment: You realize I had to close your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40518061/1415724 since it is directly related to this one. You asked for help, I told you what to do here where nobody else asked you to do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am just getting home from work. I will try it and report back asap. Sorry

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is the message i get in the error logs " PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in /var/app/current/sendemail.php on line 24"

Comment: I need you to post your full PHP and how you're using it, place it in your question and to say if it's used in the same file or separate files. The PHP you posted isn't enough code. Also, if you're using any javascript with it; the ID's suggests it for the form elements.

Comment: *"I have also tried it with the `$_POST('name')`..."* - That's because you used `()` around the POST array rather than square brackets `[]`. If that is what you're using for some of the others, there's the problem, but I won't know that for sure till you post your full code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have updated it with the full php script. Thank you

Comment: @cs1923 You're welcome. I posted something for you below. If that fails, then TBH, I don't know what else the problem could be.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have added the JS for the form. Thanks again

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is definetly the js that is causing the issue. do you know what it is?

Comment: Like I said, JS is not my bag and not the guy for this. If it works with just PHP, then you will have to either wait for someone who can pick up on the question. I wish I could help you more but I am unable to.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Fred-ii- :)

Answer (score 1):

Commenting is starting to grow too large and this is too large for a comment.

To test, use what follows instead of what you have now.

Change from:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message');
```

To:

```
if(

!empty($_POST['name']) 

&& 

!empty($_POST['number']) 

&& 

!empty($_POST['email']) 

&& 

!empty($_POST['message']) 

) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

}

else{

    echo "No empty fields please.";
    exit; // This will STOP any further execution.

}

// the rest of your code below
```

- I can't see this failing.

---

Note:

I see ID's everywhere and this suggests that you may be using additional Javascript to work with this.

Should this be the case, then you need to make sure that the syntax is correct.

This wasn't answered in my comment to you earlier.

Comment: It did not work either, I have updated the post with the JS that is used with the form. Thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

okay **found** the issue - you need to pass submit button name as a **submit** not **submited**.

Try below code:

> Your html file :

```
<form  name="contact form" method="POST" action="sendemail_1.php" id="main-contact-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="names" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email"  name="email" id="emails" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  name="number" id="numbers" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="message" id="messages" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
  </div>                        
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

> Your Php File

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: have you copy pasted my code of both the file ? its working fine here , i have checked too , in your sendemail_1.php file write code which i have written over here in your php file

Comment: yeah i just tried it, no luck, its driving me crazy

Comment: strange I have created same files and its working fine here check out again i have updated the answer

Comment: I am deploying this on my ec2 hosting, how can I see the print_r message? I am still not getting any values in the email I send

Comment: just open your sendemail_1.php file  and put this code in it - if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    print_r($_POST);
}

Comment: I have added it, no change :/

Comment: both file on are same location ? also have you remove all the code from sendemail_1.php and puted just two lines which  i have given ?

Comment: yes both same location. The sendemail_1.php file is being used but still not getting those variables over to the php. The isset doesn't look like its working

Comment: then you dont have issue with code ,this is configration related issue ,try in your local system on localhost

Comment: Does not work on localhost either. I am running a EC2 php linux environment on aws. I am not sure that the isset is evaluating to true

Comment: If you are in a Linux environment, check that you have both Read/Write permissions to the file.

Comment: When I have the isset in the sendmail_1 file the email doesn't send, when I take it out it sends, but I am still missing the variables from the form. Both files have read/write privileges

Comment: well from code side it perfects , still wait for others answer . because whatever code i have written its working fine

Comment: *"okay found the issue - you need to pass submit button name as a submit not submited.?* - I don't see what difference that would make. Had the OP used `type="submited"` I'd say fine, but the `submited` is only the name attribute, not the type; two different animals altogether.